# Need help with the steps

Tags: factoring, regular-expressions

Tried this problem several times and still cant get the right answer. Please help! https://webwork2.uncc.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/equations/ba/00ebd18c83856ce9c3b184a9a058a01.png

Comment: What is the problem? That link contains an expression.

Comment: I'm guessing you are supposed to simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the overall power of $-1$ means to invert the whole thing-you can invert the fraction inside the parentheses.  Then use the law of exponents $\frac {a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$ three times.